# tcp communication issue when new thread is triggered by timer

Tags: c, multithreading, tcp, timer

This is part of huge code where I am communicating with a robot and a s7 plc, working both in parallel. The issue is that before I though the problem was part of the plc communication, but now I have reduced all my code to a client-server application which seems also to fail. 
The code basically works in the next way; every 50ms the client sends a "hello" message to the server. When 20 messages are sent, a timer of 7 seconds is launched. When the timer is triggered a second thread is started, and this one changes the variable f=1 and it is finished. The main program in the meantime will be printing hello, but when this variable f changes to 1 it should print just "aaaaa", but it never happens.

With the PLC, the problems was segmentation fault. My idea is that the TCP communication fails (why?) and the PLC block the access. I tried the same program before just moving a robot arm, and analyzing with wireshark, you can see how the TCP are being sent all the time, but again, the robot stops. 
And finally with this client application it can be see how they didn't work as expected neither.

I hope any of you can help me.

Thanks a lot;)

CLIENT

```html
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>  // Primitive System Data Types 
#include <errno.h>      // Errors */
#include <sys/wait.h>   // Wait for Process Termination 
#include "plc_interface.h"
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

 timer_t firstTimerID;
 timer_t secondTimerID;
    struct itimerspec it;
    int t_block3=5;
 pthread_t thread_robot;
 pthread_attr_t thread_attr;
 int res, z;
 int f=0;
    


//THREAD FUNCTION ONCE THE REQUIRED BLOCK IS DETECTED
void *detection_robot(){
 printf("First\n");
 //f==1 to send the message aaaaaa
 f=1;
 pthread_exit(NULL);

}


int setTimer(timer_t * timerID, int time) {
  struct itimerspec its;
  //Interval for starting again
  its.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
  its.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
  //Timer time
  its.it_value.tv_sec = time;
  its.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
  //Arm/disarmer a per process time
  timer_settime (*timerID, 0, &its, NULL);

  return 0;
}

//TIMER INTERRUPTION
static void timerHandler (int sig, siginfo_t * si, void *uc_) {
  timer_t *tidp;
  int iret;
  tidp = si->si_value.sival_ptr;

  //Initializes the attributes for the thread
  res= pthread_attr_init(&thread_attr);
  res=pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&thread_attr,PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

    if (*tidp == firstTimerID) {
   printf ("First timer\n");

   //New thread to detect the second detection sensor
   iret = pthread_create( &thread_robot, &thread_attr, detection_robot, NULL);
   if(iret)
    {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error - pthread_create() return code: %d\n",iret);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    } else if (*tidp == secondTimerID) {
   printf ("Second timer\n");
    }

    z--;

}


//ARM THE TIMERS
static int makeTimer (timer_t * timerID) {
    struct sigevent te;
    struct sigaction sa;
    int sigNo = SIGRTMIN;
    // Set up signal handler.
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_sigaction = timerHandler;       //Action when singal is triggered
    sigemptyset (&sa.sa_mask);
    if (sigaction (sigNo, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
   perror ("sigaction");
    }
    // Set and enable alarm
    te.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;       //Gnerate alarm upon expiration
    te.sigev_signo = sigNo;       //SIGALRM
    te.sigev_value.sival_ptr = timerID;   //Timer ID
    //Create a per_process timer using the timer ID
    timer_create (CLOCK_REALTIME, &te, timerID);
  return 0;
}


int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char message[6]={'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};
       char message2[6]={'a','a','a','a','a','\0'};
    char server_reply[2000];
 //Initialize the timers
   makeTimer(&firstTimerID);
   makeTimer(&secondTimerID);

    //Create socket
    sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (sock == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");
     
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );
 
    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(sock , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        perror("connect failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Connected\n");
    //keep communicating with server
 int i=0;
 while(1){
       //Send hello every 50ms
        if( send(sock , message , 6 , 0) < 0)
        {
            puts("Send failed");
            return 1;
        }
   i++;
   if (i==20){
      setTimer (&firstTimerID, t_block3);
      i=0;
     }
     
   //f-> 1, send aaaaaa when timer is triggered, but here is when it get stacked
   if (f==1) {
    f=0;
    if( send(sock , message2 , 6 , 0) < 0)
    {
     puts("Send failed");
     return 1;
    }}

   usleep(500000); //500ms
  }

}
```

SERVER

```html
 
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>    //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include<unistd.h>    //write
 
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc , client_sock , c , read_size;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;
    char client_message[2000];
     
    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");
     
    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );
     
    //Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        //print the error message
        perror("bind failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("bind done");
     
    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , 3);
     
    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
     
    //accept connection from an incoming client
    client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);
    if (client_sock < 0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Connection accepted");
     
     while(1){
    //Receive a message from client
    recv(client_sock , client_message , 2000 , 0);
    printf("%s\n", client_message);
     
 }

}
```

Comment: what's the output? can you run it with a debugger and say where it crashed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the assignment:

```
f = 1;
```

is not visible to other threads, so the `main()` thread never sees the change. To correct, you will need to use a synchronization mechanism, such as a [`pthread_mutex_t`](https://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/manual/pthread_mutex_init.html), which must be acquired when reading or writing `f`, or [`atomic_int`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic) if your compiler has C11 support.

Comment: I tried using semaphores but it didn't work neither. I will go ahead with mutexes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED, explanation in the comments :)**

The code has been solved just adding the mutexes as hmjd proposed. Thanks ;)

I didn't have clear that it was a matter of mutex since in the other codes I am working with, there are not shared variables that can cause the code/communication breaks. I will present here my plc code, to show what I am working with. I removed extra tcp communication with the robot, I am just presenting here the continuous read of the PLC memories which works pretty stable all the time, but breaks (not always) when the simple timer is triggered. If changing the PLC for the robot which is just normal tcp communication sending move commands, still happens the same.

```html
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "nodavesimple.h"
#include "nodave.h"
#include "openSocket.h"
#include "plc_interface.h"
#include <sys/types.h>  // Primitive System Data Types
#include <errno.h>      // Errors */
#include <sys/wait.h>   // Wait for Process Termination
#include "plc_interface.h"
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#ifdef LINUX
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define UNIX_STYLE
#endif

#ifdef BCCWIN
#include <time.h>
    void usage(void);
#define WIN_STYLE

#endif


#ifdef PLAY_WITH_KEEPALIVE
#include <sys/socket.h>
#endif



 timer_t firstTimerID;
    struct itimerspec it;
    int t_block3=3;
 pthread_t thread_robot;
 pthread_attr_t thread_attr;
 int robot_detection=0;




//THREAD FUNCTION ONCE THE REQUIRED BLOCK IS DETECTED
void *detection_robot(){
 printf("First\n");
 pthread_exit(0);

}




//TIMER INTERRUPTION
static void timerHandler (int sig, siginfo_t * si, void *uc_) {
  timer_t *tidp;
  int iret;
  tidp = si->si_value.sival_ptr;

  //Initializes the attributes for the thread
  pthread_attr_init(&thread_attr);
  pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&thread_attr,PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

    if (*tidp == firstTimerID) {
   printf ("First timer\n");

   //New thread to detect the second detection sensor
   iret = pthread_create( &thread_robot, &thread_attr, detection_robot, NULL);
   if(iret)
    {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error - pthread_create() return code: %d\n",iret);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    }


}


//ARM THE TIMERS
static int makeTimer (timer_t * timerID) {
    struct sigevent te;
    struct sigaction sa;
    int sigNo = SIGRTMIN;
    // Set up signal handler.
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_sigaction = timerHandler;       //Action when singal is triggered
    sigemptyset (&sa.sa_mask);
    if (sigaction (sigNo, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
   perror ("sigaction");
    }
    // Set and enable alarm
    te.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;       //Gnerate alarm upon expiration
    te.sigev_signo = sigNo;       //SIGALRM
    te.sigev_value.sival_ptr = timerID;   //Timer ID
    //Create a per_process timer using the timer ID
    timer_create (CLOCK_REALTIME, &te, timerID);
  return 0;
}





int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int adrPos, useProtocol, useSlot;
    int res,barcode_number, r, t;
    int c=0, a=0;
    //Locate the robot in the initial position
    //robot_init();

 //Initialize the timer
   makeTimer(&firstTimerID);


#ifdef PLAY_WITH_KEEPALIVE
    int opt;
#endif

    daveSetDebug(daveDebugPrintErrors);
    adrPos=1;
    useProtocol=daveProtoISOTCP;
    useSlot=2;
    daveInterface * di;
    daveConnection * dc;
    _daveOSserialType fds;
    PDU p;
    daveResultSet rs;

    //If the input doesn't have enough parameters, printf the usage
    if (argc<2) {
  usage();
  exit(-1);
    }



 //If there is a problem in the communication it takes 20 seconds to stablish communication again
    fds.rfd=openSocket(102, argv[adrPos]);

#ifdef PLAY_WITH_KEEPALIVE
    errno=0;
    opt=1;
    res=setsockopt(fds.rfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &opt, 4);
    LOG3("setsockopt %s %d\n", strerror(errno),res);
#endif
    fds.wfd=fds.rfd;

    if (fds.rfd>0) {
 di =daveNewInterface(fds,"IF1",0, useProtocol, daveSpeed187k);
 daveSetTimeout(di,5000000);
 dc =daveNewConnection(di,2,0,useSlot);  // insert your rack and slot here
 if (0==daveConnectPLC(dc)) {
     printf("Connected.\n");

   //START THE BELT
         a=0;//a=1 to start the belt
         printf("Start the belt \n");
         res=daveWriteBits(dc,  daveDB, 111, 4, 1, &a);
         res=daveWriteBits(dc,  daveDB, 111, 3, 1, &a);
         printf("function result:%d=%s\n", res, daveStrerror(res));

    //Remove the memory flag of the detection sensor again
    res=daveWriteBits(dc,  daveFlags, 0, 504, 1, &c);
    res=daveWriteBits(dc,  daveFlags, 0, 520, 1, &c);

    usleep(2000000);
    printf("Trying to read the sensor until block is detected\n");
    //SENSOR DETECTION
    while(1){

     //Read request  --> Stable until the timer is triggered
     davePrepareReadRequest(dc,&p);
     daveAddVarToReadRequest(&p, daveFlags, 0, 63, 1);
     daveAddVarToReadRequest(&p, daveFlags, 0, 65, 1);
     daveAddVarToReadRequest(&p, daveDB, 4, 103, 1);
     res=daveExecReadRequest(dc, &p, &rs);
     if (res==1){ printf("Error during the request\n");}

     //First result --> detection sensor after the barcode
     res=daveUseResult(dc, &rs, 0);
     if (res==1){ printf("Error reading the first result\n");}
        t=daveGetU8(dc); //T = 1 if detection in the barcode place
        //Second result --> detection sensor before the robot position
     res=daveUseResult(dc, &rs, 1);
     if (res==1){ printf("Error reading the detection sensor before the robot\n");}
     r=daveGetU8(dc); //R = 1 if detection in the robot place
     //Third result --> read the number stored
     daveUseResult(dc, &rs, 2);
     barcode_number=daveGetU8(dc);
     //Free the memory
     daveFreeResults(&rs);

     if (r==1){
      //Remove the memory flag referred to the second sensor
      res=daveWriteBits(dc,  daveFlags, 0, 520, 1, &c);
      if (res==1){ printf("Error removing the flag of the second detector\n");}
     }

     //Wen detection..
     if (t==1){
       t=0;
       //Remove the memory flag of the detection
       res=daveWriteBits(dc,  daveFlags, 0, 504, 1, &c);
       if (res==1){ printf("Error removing the flag of the sensor closed to the robot\n");}


       //If number three is detected the belt will stop in 3 seconds respectively
       switch(barcode_number){

       case 3: printf("Block number three, timer will be triggered in 3 seconds\n");
         //Start the timer
         setTimer (&firstTimerID, t_block3);
         break;

       case 2: printf("Block number two, belt won't stop\n");
         break;

       case 4: printf("Block number four, belt won't stop\n");
         break;

       default:printf("Wrong lecture\n");

       }}


     usleep(50000); //Rest until next sampling
  }
 //Close socket
 closeSocket(fds.rfd);
 printf("Finished.\n");

 return 0;
 } else {//daveconnected
     printf("Couldn't connect to PLC.\n \n");
     closeSocket(fds.rfd);
     return -2;}

    }//fds.rds > 0
     else {
 printf("Couldn't open TCP port. \nPlease make sure a CP is connected and the IP address is ok. \n");
     return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally I have solved all the problems. I will try to clarify them. For the robot. You send some tcp commands and you have to sleep for a while, waiting until the robot reach the position you asked for. And then send the new tcp command for the new position. With timers, when it is triggered, could be that the robot is in waiting until reach the position, so if the time is triggered, when timerhandler finishes, the code executes the next line, without leaving the robot enough time to reach the position... and it breaks. This robot is the UR10.

Comment: For the code I just presented above is exactly the same. The  instructions which request access to the memory, it can happen that the timer is triggered and jumps one of this important instructions. And then, in the next instructions it tries to read one of the memories was not requested before, making a segmentation fault.